# Disk space consumption for document class

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet, filenet-image-services

I have FileNet Image Services, version 4.0.40 (not 100% sure). No access to the administrative interface, only Unix console, and database (Oracle). I need to get total document size, and also size of specific document class on disk. How do I do that?

Comment: You might find this useful — http://www.ecmplace.com/viewtopic.php?p=72137#p72137

Answer (score -1):

Normally you would use the API with the call `get_ContentSize()`. If you can access the database, look for the docversion table in the object store db, I think you can also get the property directly from the DB there, If you then join the table with the classdefinition table you can look.

Here is an example of the query

```
select dv.object_id, vd.content_size from objectstore.docversion dv 
inner join objectstore.classdefinition cl on dv.object_class_id = cl.object_id
where cl.symbolic_name = 'yourclassname'
```

Comment: The question is about Image Services, not Content Engine.